# Regex blows up in an editor extension

Tags: .net, regex, mef

I am building a Visual Studio editor extension for my Django rendering engine. I just started it so so far it is really simple and so far it does what I expect it to do - highlighting and the such. 
Or it did until I started to add parsing logic. Part of the parsing relies on regular expressions. And here is my problem:
No matter how I try - static variables, member variables, - anything, every time I call new Regex it gives me "Object not set to an instance" exception.
Is there a problem with using regular expressions (RegEx) in MEF?

here you go:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace NDjango.Designer.Parsing
    {
        public interface IParser
        {
             List<Token> Parse(IEnumerable<string> template);
        }

        [Export(typeof(IParser))]
        public class Parser : IParser
        {
            public List<Token> Parse(IEnumerable<string> template)
            {
                var result = new List<Token>();
                Regex tag_re = new Regex("({{.*}}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

A breakpoint on the line with the Regex constructor is hit just fine. The next F10 gives the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry guys, I figured it out, JaredPar you were right - the problem was unbalanced paren in the regexp. The "diagnostic" though was quiet misleading to say the least

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no issue with using regular expressions in MEF.  The issue is in your code.

Based on the error message it looks like you are hitting a null reference exception when you try and create a new regex.  Without seeing a code sample it's not easy to know what exactly is going wrong.

Can you post a code sample?

Comment: sure here it is:
namespace NDjango.Designer.Parsing
{
    [Export(typeof(IParser))]
    public class Parser : IParser
    {
        public List<Token> Parse(IEnumerable<string> template)
        {
            var result = new List<Token>();
            Regex tag_re = new Regex("({{.*}}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
When I put the breakpoint on the new Regex line it hits it just fine, but the next F10 - boom!!!

Comment: @mfeingold - The appropriate way to publish this code snippet would be to edit your question and add it there.